# Alter and set a id attribute for a field in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, alter

Can anyone help me how to alter a field attribute in drupal 7. Let say i have created a field name hello_test with label as hello.Now I need to alter the label and set a attribute for the filed in template.php file in my theme.Can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem a few days ago. When I set a textfield attribute onblur and onfocus, it didn't work. To be precise, it was working but I couldn't see it because it was overwritten by a form alter of the profile2 modules.

I think your form alter api loads before a profile2 module form alter api. So gets overwritten. I solved my problem by creating a custom form alter in another namespace.

```
    function yourCustomModuleName_form_profile2_edit_testing_candidate_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

   $form['profile_testing_candidate']["field_candidate_name"] = array(
        "#title" => "Candidate Name",
        "#type" => "textfield",
        "#required" => TRUE,
        "#description" => t(""),
        '#default_value' => 'Given Name',
        '#attributes' => array (
            'onblur' => "if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Given Name'}",
            'onfocus' => "if (this.value == 'Given Name') {this.value = ''}",
        ),
   );

   $form['profile_testing_candidate']["field_candidate_family_name"] = array(
        "#title" => "",
        "#type" => "textfield",
        "#required" => FALSE,
        "#description" => t(""),
        '#default_value' => 'Family Name',
        '#attributes' => array (
               'onblur' => "if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Family Name'}",
               'onfocus' => "if (this.value == 'Family Name') {this.value = ''}",
        ),
   );
}
```